# SimpleJpaRepository (CrudRepository) and @Transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In SimpleJpaRepository (implements CrudRepository) method save() has @Transactional annotation. This means that entitymanagers transaction starts at the launch of save() and commits after save() return?
Therefore entity becomes detached after save() return?

Comment: Unless there's already a surrounding transaction, yes, it means precisely that. If there's a surrounding transaction, the method call will inherit the caller's transaction context, and no entities will automatically become detached until *that* transaction ends

Comment: Do you mean  by "surrounding transaction" transaction like following?

Comment: em.getTransaction().begin();
repository.save(entity);
em.getTransaction().commit();

Comment: No, I mean 'surrounding transaction' coming from calling the repository method from another `@Transactional` method